# How can I switch between "test" and "production" Salesforce Enterprise WSDL web reference classes?

Tags: c#, wsdl, salesforce, web-reference

I have created web references in my Visual Studio console project using WSDL files for Salesforce production and Salesforce sandbox.

I am trying to write the program like so:

```
ServiceClass client;
if(Debug)
{
     client = Test.SforceService;
}
else
{
     client = Prod.SforceService;
}
```

Problem is, the `SforceService` class is auto-generated, so I can't implement the ServiceClass in their files.

What are my options?

Comment: Do the wsdl files differ?

Comment: Yes, in numerous places.

Comment: If they are exact, you don't have to switch between classes at all. That's why I'm asking.

Answer (score 0):

When you inspect the WSDL at the end there should be something like this:

```
<service name="SforceService">
    <documentation>Sforce SOAP API</documentation>
    <port binding="tns:SoapBinding" name="Soap">
        <soap:address location="https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/48.0"/>
    </port>
</service>
```

My C# days are long gone but try to look for matching section in the generated class. If it's a String property you should be able to override the default value with `login.salesforce.com` (or other way around) in runtime?